# IF function for currency exchange

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to use an IF function in excel that calculates how much an item would cost in a different country. Image 1 has the cost price of two different countries and also where the new cost needs to go. In image two (which is also in a different sheet) the first row in the third column says AD now that is the exchange rate that needs to go into image one where it says cost price (AU). Now if I change that AD to SV it is suppose to change the cost price (AU) in image 1. The IF function includes rounding to 2 decimal places into each calculation of the IF function and error checking.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I hope this makes sense and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want. If you tell us what you've tried, it may become clearer.

Comment: Not very clearly about your requirement, di you want to create a formula in Image 1 Cost Price (AU)??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sheet with the exchange rates is 'Sheet2' and that the column with the exchange rates is column 'C' and that the rows shown of 'Sheet2' are 1, 2 and 3, you can enter in `W4`:

```
=IF(Sheet2!C$1="AD"; ROUND(U4*Sheet2!C$2;2); IF(Sheet2!C$1="SV"; ROUND(V4*Sheet2!C$3;2); "Err"))
```

and copy down as needed.

Note! Depending on your language version you might need to change the delimiters in the formula.